# Fetch Google+ emails from Google People API

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-people-api

I'm doing like this.

```
    ListConnectionsResponse r = peopleService.people().connections()
            .list("people/me")
            .setPageSize(500)
            // specify fields to be returned
            .setRequestMaskIncludeField("person.names,person.emailAddresses")
            .execute();
```

It returns a list of my connections with emails I have added myself. But not the information gathered from Google+ profiles. Is this possible to fetch also? I tried fetching the individual resourceName, but no email there.

```
    Person p = peopleService.people().get("people/XXxxx").execute();
```

Comment: did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The Google People API actually does fetch the emails from Google+ profiles, but only the **public** e-mails. So if the e-mail shows up when you view their profile when not signed in, then it should show up in the response.

However, e-mails that are not public but are shared with your account (e-mails you can only see if you are signed in) are **NOT** visible through the Google People API for privacy reasons.